# jQuery event.which not working in IE

Tags: jquery, events

I am trying to get the code of an event using the event.which jQuery function. It is working great in FF, but in IE8 I am only getting "undefined". Is there some reason this would not work in IE8? I am using jQuery version 1.3.2 and the code is bellow (simplified).

```
function handleInput(event) {
   //Get the character code of the pressed button
   keycode = event.which;
}
```

Thanks,
Metropolis

** EDITED **

Basically what I want to be able to do is have an HTML element with an onkeyup event attribute which will call to the handleInput function. Here is what I want the HTML to look like.

```
<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="handleInput(event)" />
```

Is there a way to pass "event" like this and have jQuery recognize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does support [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/). How exactly are you binding your handler? Are you using jQuery? If you're doing:

```
jQuery("#element").click(function(evt) {
 //evt is a jQuery-normalized event object

});
```

It should work. You probably don't want to use `event` (notice that I am passing in `evt` versus `event`) as the parameter since it will collide with IE's [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863%28VS.85%29.aspx) object. I believe this is the source of your problem.

**EDIT**

After reading your comment, you need to do something like this in a Javascript file that you reference from `<HEAD>`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   //event-handling binding-code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vivin. Right now I am calling this function from an HTML element and passing "event". Is there a way to pass in an event like this and have jQuery recognize it? I will not always know which element I am attaching it to since it is dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the element is dynamic?

Comment: Well I am using this inside a library, so I will be using this function in many different places. I did not really want to be adding the jQuery("#element").click inside a javascript file on every project I use this in. I was hoping to be able to keep it inline with an HTML element like above.

Comment: Well either way you need to separate presentation (HTML) from behavior (Javascript). So you would need at the very least a Javascript file that you reference in `<HEAD>`. Check out my answer for an example

Comment: I know I can do it that way.....I was just wanting to know if there is a way to do it the way I showed above?

Comment: I don't believe so. Even if it were, that would be a risky way. Why would you want to use `event` when you know it's ambiguous? So my suggestion is to programmatically bind events :)

Comment: Ok, thanks Vivin for all your help. I will just assume I can not do it, and forget about trying to do it that way :)

Comment: I'm assuming the way you wanted to do it was with the `event` object? Yeah, that would be harder. As far as writing in the code in HTML I believe you *can* do that with jQuery, but I would advise against it. It's much better when you separate behavior from presentation. Makes it easier in the long run :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same experience in IE9.  It can be fixed by using `mousedown` or `mouseup` rather than `click`.

Answer (score -1):

These before guys are ignorant to the facts, see here --> http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

I'm not sure what i'm doing different, but my companies software uses e.which like crazy and runs perfectly fine in IE 7-9

see working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/KCzvh/)

Comment: also, try using `$.browser` to determine browser type,
`if ($.browser.safari) {
 // do work
}
else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
 // do work
}
else if ($.browser.msie) {
 // do work
}`

Comment: Yes I know. It has been a long time since I looked at this problem, but it obviously does not seem to be a problem anymore lol. I have no idea what I did, and I am not sure why I accepted the above answer. But I must have had a good reason for it. I do not advocate using $.browser. Im pretty sure its deprecated also.