# Internet Explorer showing e.which as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

In `Internet Explorer 8`, `event.which` is showing `undefined` and working fine in FireFox and `IE 9`. I am using the `Textbox` 'onkeypress' Event

### MarkUp

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1" MaxLength="3"
                        onkeypress="return MainCheckStrings(event);" />
```

### It is working fine in FF, Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer - 9

Any Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412419/jquery-event-which-not-working-in-ie

Comment: SO thread with an explanation of why. hint: searching is your friend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050984/javascript-event-e-which

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly shows that this property is available only from IE 9 onwards.

Comment: @Guest: Chuck found your link. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3051784/50079). Specifically, the *"For `keypress` events..."* part.

Answer (score 1):

In IE prior 9 the even object is not the same as others so you need to handle that case specifically and same goes for the which property.

```
function MainCheckStrings(e) {
    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;  // Get event details for IE
        e.which = e.keyCode; // assign which property (so rest of the code works using e.which)
    }
};
```

Here is a good article on the subject that should explains everything clearly http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: Updated so you can see it. In some IE it doesn't exists but you can assign it and use the rest of the code as expected.