# Is there a jQuery plugin that normalizes browser key codes?

Tags: jquery, keycode

Is there a jQuery plugin that normalizes key codes cross-browser?  Meaning, if you press a certain key, then you are guaranteed to get the same key code for every browser that you test in?

Comment: It's called [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, however, it is built into jQuery!

```
$("element").on("keypress",function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `which` property of the event object is defined for key and mouse events in most browsers, but not IE < 9. jQuery, however normalizes this support: [e.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) (Thanks @RocketHazmat for pointing this out)

```
$(this).keyup(function(e) {
    var code = e.which;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you do that? `The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.` http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: So you place `e.keyCode` to account for IE <= 8?

Comment: `e.which` works fine in IE8.

Comment: For ie support see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315260/internet-explorer-showing-e-which-as-undefined

Comment: @benedict_w: jQuery adds `e.which`, it's not *natively* in IE < 9.

Comment: I see @RocketHazmat - good call

Comment: @benedict_w: Your example is using jQuery already, so `|| e.keyCode` is completly useless.

Comment: Thanks I've edited my answer and credited you