# jQuery javascript keypress function not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've the following jquery function which avoid typing "1" in the input text:

```
<input id="myId" style="width:50%;" value="0" type="text">​

$("#myId").keypress(function(e) {
   var x=e.charCode;
   if (x == '49'){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});​
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqUEV/2/)

which is not working on IE8. Where is my error? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT JAVASCRIPT VERSION**

```
<input id="myId" style="width:50%;" value="0" type="text"  onkeypress="javascript:checkNumber(event);"/>

function checkNumber(event) {
var x=e.which;
if (x == 49){
    event.preventDefault();
}
}
```

Comment: Mandatoried link: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`charCode` is not cross-browser, you can use jQuery [`which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property:

> The `event.which` property normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It is recommended to watch `event.which` for keyboard key input.

```
var x = e.which;
```

If you don't use jQuery, you can code:

```
var x = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
```

Comment: According to [this well written answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3051784/1243160), "which is a property of Event objects. It is defined for key-related and mouse-related events in most browsers, but in both cases is not defined in IE (prior to version 9)."

Comment: Apologies: I realize that jQuery `which` addresses this. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2412501/1243160) suggests passing the `event` by a different name so as not to conflict with IE's event object.

Comment: @crowjonah Yes, jQuery normalizes that.

Comment: @undefined that's working but how about javascript?? See my edit please

Comment: @undefined it says "method or property not supported" referring to
event.preventDefault();

Comment: @Franky IE8 doesn't support preventDefault method check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/492873/1243160) to a similar question. Try `keydown` instead of `keypress` and `keyCode` instead of `charCode`:

```
$("#myId").keydown(function(e) {
   var x=e.keyCode;
   if (x == '49'){
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});​
```

the [jQuery documentation for keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) lists a few good reasons to use `keydown` instead, not the least of which is that it only fires once for a press and hold, and keypress reports the character, not the key (which is problematic when dealing with things like capslock.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.which` instead, since `e.charCode` isn't supported on all browsers.

Also, you might consider using `.keyup()` event instead of `.keypress()`